# Matlab Cant see Variables on Workspace

Tags: user-interface, workspace, matlab

I have a problem with my Workspace. I am trying to see my GUI variables on workspace, but I can't! For example I run a .m file gui and open interface. For example  I open any image and  making image processing for kind of images.But I can't see any variables appear in the workspace. I don't want to use save variable(because of my supervisor's demand). Is there any way to see it on workspace GUI m-file.
what can I do with this, any idea?

Thanks by now

Answer (score 2):

The usual workspace that you see is usually referred to as **base** workspace (see "[base and function workspaces](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html)"). Then, any function has its own separate workspace, which means that either you explicitly return variables with an output argument:

```
out = foo(in)
...
```

or you can use `assignin()` in conjunction with a callback attached to a button to push the variables to the base workspace (see this technical solution for more details "[How can I output variables from a GUI to the workspace in MATLAB 7.8 (R2009a)?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-9FZUOY/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-9FZUOY)".

Ultimately, it would be a good investment if you read "[Data Management in a Programmatic GUI](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-manage-data-in-a-programmatic-gui.html)".